# Writing the integral $ \int_{t}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{4\pi s^{3}})^{1/2}\frac{r(|x|-r)}{|x|}e^{-\frac{(|x|-r)^{2}}{4s}}ds$ in simpler form?

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if 
$\int_{t}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{4\pi s^{3}})^{1/2}\frac{r(|x|-r)}{|x|}e^{-\frac{(|x|-r)^{2}}{4s}}ds$ can be written more simply,  where $x,r\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

wolfram alpha doesn't give me anything.

Here are my attempts ( I will type as I go):

1)Taylor expansion

$\frac{r(|x|-r)}{|x|}\frac{1}{2\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(|x|-r)^{2k}}{k!}(\frac{3}{2}+k+1)\frac{1}{t^{\frac{5}{2}+k}}$

I would like to get a big O estimate for it eg. $O(t^{\alpha})$. So does the above sum converge to some closed expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be simplified a lot. (I assume that $t \gt 0$ as well.)  Take out the constants to get

$$\frac1{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \frac{r}{|x|} (|x|-r) \int_t^{\infty} ds \, s^{-3/2} e^{-(|x|-r)^2/(4 s)}$$

Sub $s=1/u^2$ to get that the integral is equal to

$$\frac1{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{r}{|x|} (|x|-r) \int_0^{1/\sqrt{t}} du \, e^{-(|x|-r)^2 u^2} $$

This is easily expressed in terms of an error function:
$$ \frac{r}{2 |x|} \operatorname{erf}{\left ( \frac{|x|-r}{\sqrt{t}} \right )} $$

Comment: to be honest I wanted to get a big O notation for t. It is not clear to me, how to do that with the error function.

Comment: For what?  As $t \to  \infty$?  In that case, then the integral is simply $O(1/\sqrt{t})$ because, for small $x$, $\operatorname{erf}{(x)} = O(x)$.

Comment: x is fixed and yes as $t\to \infty$. I don't see how the above estimate follows from the erf.

Comment: @TKM: well, then, there you go.  You can get a more precise approximation from the Taylor series of the erf.

Comment: but how can I remove the k. Or does it imply $O(t^{\frac{5}{2}})$.

Comment: Better to consider a Taylor series from the integral form in my answer over $u$.  There, the lowest order term is clearly $1/\sqrt{t}$ from integrating the Taylor series of the exponential.